# Removing carriage returns from Scrapy screen output

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit to run scrapy. I am using the following to remove \n \r characters and html tags from my screen output:

```
body = response.xpath("//p").extract()
            body2 = str(body)
            body3 = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', body2)
            print remove_tags(body3)
```

This removes the HTML special characters fine, however the \r \n characters are not being removed from the final output. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: change `\s{2,}` to `\s+`

Comment: @kev thanks for replying again. i'm afraid that hasn't worked. a sample output i am still getting is 'ehind Mercedes team-mate Nico Rosberg \n \r\nin this season\'s dramatic title race, \r\n\n despite having'. im not great with regular expressions, so im not sure what your suggested change is doing logic wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

buddy what you need is the regex

```
(\\[rn]|\s){2,}
```

try this out and let me know if this worked out.

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. the line 'body3 = re.sub(r'(\\[rn]|\s){2,}', ' ', body2)' including your suggestion got rid of \r\n\n type groupings, however I still have some remaining \n & \t breaks in the output. could you suggest a syntax for dropping them also? thanks

Comment: actually, 'body3 = re.sub(r'(\\[rn]|\s){2,}', ' ', body2)
            body4 = re.sub(r'(\\[t]|\s){2,}', ' ', body3)' shifts \r\n\n combos and \t, however using 'body5 = re.sub(r'(\\[n]|\s){2,}', ' ', body4)' to get rid of \n does not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since you are not sure what type of newline the document contains you should replace your pattern with:

```
\s{2,}|[\r\n]
```

Indeed, most of the time, newlines can be CRLF *(windows convention)*, or only LF *(unix convention)* (that is probably the case with you current document.) or only CR *(for old apple OS)*

Comment: thanks for replying. so i should use the complete line 'body3 = re.sub(r'[^\S\r\n]*[\r\n]+\s*|\s{2,})'?

Comment: @user3045351: Yes, but see my edit with a very more simple pattern.

Comment: 'body3 = re.sub(r'\s{2,}|[\r\n]', ' ', body2)' again does not remove the characters. sample output: ' session, \r\n\n was sixth.\n', u" The Finn's team-mate Felipe Massa, who suffered a heavy'...

Comment: @user3045351: Are you sure that your sample text contain CR and LF characters? Are you sure that it isn't a literal backslash followed by a literal `n` or `r`?

Comment: This is the source page: http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/formula1/28166984 is there a difference between CR & LF and regular line breaks? im fairly new to python, javascript and html.

Comment: according to that link html \n, \r & \r\n characters should all be CR+LF characters? i dont understand why this isnt working in that case...